# Angular Karma/Jesmine spyOn creates type '"x"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a constant class below. When I try to return a different value using spyOn in order to test error cases, ng test return compile time error Argument of type '`"retryCount"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

is there a way to get around this?

```
 export class NConstants {
  public static retryCount: number = 2;
  public static readonly retryDelayInMilliseconds: number = 10000; // ms
  public static readonly retryNotificationDelayInSeconds: number = 50;
}


spyOn(NetworkConstants, 'retryCount').and.returnValue(0);
```

all packages

```
    "jasmine-auto-spies": "^4.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-trx-reporter": "^0.3.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only `spyOn` methods/functions of the class, not instance variables.

To change it to return 0, just modify it directly.

```
NConstants.retryCount = 0;
// do what you want.
// further down the line, you can reset it
NConstants.retryCounter = 2;
```